# Using ! in a function

Tags: functions

I have the following command for arranging a few lines in a file using `sed` and `column`:

```
:-3,+2!sed 's/- 2021/\&2021/' | sed 's/ 2021/\&2021/' | column -s '&' -t
```

This works fine. For example, the following buffer:

```
  a - 2021-01-01
  b     - 2021-04-05
```

Gets formatted into:

```
  a       2021-01-01
  b       2021-04-05
```

I would like to use this as part of a larger function. However, that does not seem to work. If I define it like this:

```
function Test()
  normal :-3,+2!sed 's/- 2021/\&2021/' | sed 's/ 2021/\&2021/' | column -s '&' -t
endfunction
```

And enter `:call Test()<CR>`, nothing happens. But if I enter the command directly, it works fine.

I have read about `system()`, but I don’t know yet how to pass lines into there, then removing the old lines from the buffer, etc. Is there any way to make the `!` command work in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `normal`; you want to run an Ex command, so just run it:

```
-3,+2!sed …
```

and note that you can define functions which take ranges (you'll need `:execute …` at that point).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xnoremap <F3> :<c-u>call Test()<cr>

function Test() abort
    let shellcmd = 'sed ''s/- 2021/\&2021/'' | sed ''s/ 2021/\&2021/'' | column -s ''&'' -t'
    let oldlines = getline("'<", "'>") + ['']
    let @" = system(shellcmd, oldlines)
    normal! gvp
endfunction
```

Visually select your lines, then press `<F3>`.

For more info, see:

- [:h getline()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getline())
- [:h system()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system())
- [:h gv](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#gv)